# Infinite loop while trying to read from file

Tags: c, file, fopen, infinite-loop

I wanted to read bytes from file and then rewrite them.
I did like so:

```
FILE *fp;
int cCurrent;
long currentPos;

/* check if the file is openable */
if( (fp = fopen(szFileName, "r+")) != NULL )
{
    /* loop for each byte in the file crypt and rewrite */
    while(cCurrent != EOF)
    {
        /* save current position */
        currentPos = ftell(fp);
        /* get the current byte */
        cCurrent = fgetc(fp);
        /* XOR it */
        cCurrent ^= 0x10;
        /* take the position indicator back to the last position */
        fseek(fp, currentPos, SEEK_SET);
        /* set the current byte */
        fputc(cCurrent, fp);
    }
```

After executing the code on a file, the size of the file is increasing within an infinite loop.

What is the problem in my code?

Comment: You are supposed to do an `fseek()`, even if it is just `fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_CUR);`, after the write (`fputc()`) and before the next read (`fgetc()`).  On an update stream, there is supposed to be a seek-like operation between each change between reading and writing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Why I have to do the fseek?

Comment: Because the C standard says the behaviour is undefined if you don't.  The dangerous thing about undefined behaviour is that it may do just what you expect on your current system, but if the compiler (or library) changes, or you move to a different machine, then the program that used to work may stop working — and both implementations are perfectly correct.

Comment: ISO/IEC 9899:2011, §7.21.5.3 _The `fopen` function. ¶7 When a file is opened with update mode ('+' as the second or third character in the
above list of mode argument values), both input and output may be performed on the
associated stream. However, output shall not be directly followed by input without an
intervening call to the `fflush` function or to a file positioning function (`fseek`,
`fsetpos`, or `rewind`), and input shall not be directly followed by output without an
intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end-of-
file._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are `XOR`-ing `cCurrent` with `0x10` even if it's equal to `EOF`. Once you `XOR`, it's no longer `EOF`, so your loop never terminates.

Make the loop infinite, and exit from the middle when you see an `EOF`, like this:

```
for (;;)  {
    /* save current position */
    currentPos = ftell(fp);
    /* get the current byte */
    if ((cCurrent = fgetc(fp)) == EOF) {
        break;
    }
    /* XOR it */
    cCurrent ^= 0x10;
    /* take the position indicator back to the last position */
    fseek(fp, currentPos, SEEK_SET);
    /* set the current byte */
    fputc(cCurrent, fp);
    /* reset stream for next read operation */
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_CUR);
}
```

Comment: Suggest parentheses around assignment in `if (cCurrent = fgetc(fp) == EOF) {`, it won't work properly without.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you very much, you are absolutely right.